# How to handle a specific error from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity, returned while creating user with password?

Tags: error-handling, asp.net-core-identity

How to handle specific error (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityError`) returned during creating user by using (`UserManager<TUser>`)class. For example, I want to do something if the error is: `PasswordTooShort or PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric`. Now I get information about errors but idk how to handle them.

[image: Information about error]

I don't want to do something like `if(IdentityError == "name of error" {do something})`, I'm looking for smarter solution... I looked through a lot of topics but cannot find an answer to my question, if you know one, please redirect me...

EDIT: I made something like this:

```
if (createResult.Errors.Any(x => x.Code == "PasswordTooShort"))
        {
            var errorContent = "kielbaska";
            return RedirectToAction("ShowError", new ErrorFM
            {
                ErrorContent = errorContent
            });
        }
```

But I want to replace error name from brackets with error name from list of available result failed errors, for example something like this`usrManager.ErrorDescriber.PasswordTooShort`(just and example)

Comment: You mean you don't want to write too many wrong names, but put the errors in a set and then compare with the errors in the set?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, if this is only soultution it's a good solution :), but I was thinking of object that soteres the error messages.